# How does gcc implement inline assembly to specify a register?

Tags: c, gcc

When I read gcc doc, I noticed that We can use inline assembly to specify a register, through bounding to a C value.

```c
register int *p1 asm ("r0") = …;
register int *p2 asm ("r1") = …;
register int *result asm ("r0");
asm ("sysint" : "=r" (result) : "0" (p1), "r" (p2));
```

I am very curious how gcc implements this feature, because some description in the [doc](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Local-Register-Variables.html) confused me. I don't know the assembly these C code will be compiled to, that makes me very scary to use these feature.

Comment: What part causes the confusion? Here `sysint` *is* the assembly code generated, with the compiler making sure that the parameters are loaded into `r0` and `r1`. The `register` keyword has been part of C all along, asking the compiler to put a frequently used variable into a register as an optimization. The extension here just allows you to select a specific register.

Comment: What sort of answer are you expecting to “How does gcc implement…” this? There is source code in GCC to make it work, that is how. GCC maintains internal data that it uses to determine how to use registers in the assembly code it generates. What other answer are you looking for?

Comment: When I used `register asm` feature, is the C-value was bind dynamicly to the register(When the register changed, the C-value changed; the C-value changed, the register changed)? And is the register will not be allocated to other use(argument pass, caculate, return value, tmp use...)? Can I give two different C-value the same register? Can I bind all register to the C-value, which may cause there are no registers to use? I don't know the rule about it.

Comment: Are these four lines taken as-is from "read gcc docs"?

Comment: Remember that *The only supported use for [local registers] is to specify registers for input and output operands when calling Extended asm*.  So you should only assume the 'current' value of the c variable will be in the register upon entering the asm instructions.  There are no other guarantees about the register contents.  Which means the compiler is free to use the register for other purposes as required.  Other than for use in asm, trying to force c variables into specific registers is almost certainly a bad idea, as is [using inline asm](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/DontUseInlineAsm) at all.